# Getting camera attached to same object as script

Tags: unity-game-engine

My player is setup like this:

```
Hero (GameObject)
      Camera (child of Hero)
      Model (child of Hero)
```

I have attached a script to "Hero".

In this script I have stated the following to get the attached camera:

```
private Camera _camera;

void Start()
{
    _camera = this.GetComponent<Camera>();
```

However, this fails at runtime.

The error I'm getting is:

MissingComponentException: There is 'Camera' attached to the "Hero" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

What is my error here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

The camera is not attached DIRECTLY to the hero, but as a child, therefore I need to use the following:

```
    _camera = this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
```